# ColdFusion CFLayout does not wotk with cfif?

Tags: coldfusion-10

I'm trying to do this but it seems that both of the included templates are being shown on the page. It's like the cfif cfelse are being ignored:

```
<cflayout type="tab" name="GroupTab" width="910" height="560">
    <cflayoutarea name="IssuesTab" selected="#isSelected#"      
                             title="SoftwareIssues" style="height:100%">
      <br>
      <CFIF IsDefined("url.item")>
    <cfinclude template ="addnew.cfm>

      <CFELSE>
         <cfinclude template="issues.cfm">
      </CFIF>
   </cflayoutarea>
</cflayout>
```

Can't I do that with cflayout? I'm working within the scope of iFrame.
If cflayout does not allow using cfif cfelse is there any work around?

Comment: Please ignore my entry, I solve it by doing it by setting the cfif and cfelse outside the cflayout and then put the template name inside the cflayoutarea

Answer (score 1):

Ifelse condition is  working well with cflayout

You have forgot " at the end of file name

Your
`<cfinclude template ="addnew.cfm>`

correct one 
`<cfinclude template ="addnew.cfm">`